# How can I simulate a click event on an anchor tag without actually calling click or refreshing?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am using meteor with iron router and meteors standard blaze tempting.

I have an ul set up so that when one of my li items is clicked its containing anchor tag is clicked on using the function click. The only problem is that when that a is clicked with the function it counts as another click on my li and my menu isn't toggling right.

I am wondering if there is a way to call the pathFor without actually calling a click function.

Thanks for any help!

Update, here is the code its working along with a pretty standard drop down nav. I am not sure if I can catch that event the same as a jquery event since I think it is the standard browser click event working on the [0], but I think I should be able to make a function that matches href to route and call Router.go

```
Template.nav.rendered = () ->
    # set initial page view and take care of refeshes
    currentPageHtlm = getCurrentPage(window.location.pathname)
    $('#currentPage').find('span').html(currentPageHtlm)

    $("li").on "click", () ->
        #simulate anchor click and set currentPage session
        $(this).find("a")[0].click()
        Session.set 'pageName', getCurrentPage($(this).find("a").attr("href"))
        currentPageHtlm = Session.get 'pageName'
        $('#currentPage').find('span').html(currentPageHtlm)

        # toggle nav and arrow if mobile view
        if $('.smOnly').css('display') != 'none'
            $('#nav').slideToggle('slow')
            $('#dropArrow').toggleClass('fa-caret-square-o-down fa-caret-square-o-up')
```

Comment: share your js code..you should try `e.stopPropagation()` and `e.preventDefault()` to avoid event bubbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to programatically redirect from JS rather than via UI interaction, in which case you need to use `Router.go('ROUTE_NAME')`, as per [the docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#using-javascript) (you can use the route name as in `pathFor` as an alternative to supplying the actual path).